# Heroku flask deployment issue - logs shows gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: app:app

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn

We have a small flask project here https://github.com/codesydney/OPEND

It is working as expected locally. However, when deployed to heroku, it keeps on throwing gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: app:app.

Procfile content is "web: gunicorn app:app".

Thanks in advance for your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your should write in your procfile this:

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

Leftside argument is a name of the app that will be launched. In your case it's run.py.

Comment: Thanks mate. We tried your suggestion but did not work either. What we found out is that the taking of arguments seems to be the one causing the issue. We tried hardcoding values instead of passing arguments and it worked even with "web: gunicorn app:app". We may need explore more about that arguments contraints. Thanks for your time responding. Cheers!