# gunicorn : error: unrecognized arguments when running flask app in Docker

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile, google-compute-engine, gunicorn

Disclaimer: I am pretty green with Docker and gunicorn. 
I am running a Flask application inside a docker container. I am running the following:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -it my-image:0.1
```

and in the logs:

```
[2019-09-18 18:02:21 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
usage: gunicorn [-h] [--model MODEL] [--cam_id CAM_ID] [--cam_width 
 CAM_WIDTH]
            [--cam_height CAM_HEIGHT] [--scale_factor SCALE_FACTOR]
            [--notxt]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: -b :8080 main:app
```

I know this question has been asked multiple times ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851353/heroku-flask-deployment-issue-logs-shows-gunicorn-error-unrecognized-argumen), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748015/configuring-gunicorn-no-application-module-specified), and [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1841) for example) but none of the answers seemed to help.

Here is the content of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-gpu.1-1

RUN apt-get update
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "main:app"]
```

and `main.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import model

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/getduration', methods=['POST'])
def get_duration():
    try:
        video_url = request.args.get('video')
    except:
        video_url = None   
    try:
        duration = model.run(video_url)
        result = str(duration)
        return result, 200
    except Exception as e:
        error = f"There was an error: {e}"
        return error, 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I've tried creating a wsgi.py file containing:

```
from main import app

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

then changed my Dockerfile entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "wsgi:app"]
```

What am I missing?

Note that if I just run `python main.py` inside my container, my flask app works fine. When I changed my `Dockerfile` entrypoint to `CMD ["python", "main.py"]`, the server runs, but I don't get any response when I make requests.

Comment: are you running this in a GCP instance? or why google-compute-engine tag was added?

Comment: yeah, running it on a deep learning VM on GCP

Comment: try exposing your port in your Dockerfile. Add `EXPOSE 8080` at the end.

Comment: I tried that too. Same outcome.

Comment: make 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

Comment: @Adiii That didn't work either. Same issue

Comment: I am really confused about the gunicorn arguments options given in my error. Any ideas on what those mean? (`[--model MODEL] [--cam_id CAM_ID] [--cam_width CAM_WIDTH]  [--cam_height CAM_HEIGHT] [--scale_factor SCALE_FACTOR] [--notxt]`. Am I using some weird gunicorn here? (`gunicorn==19.9.0`)

Comment: Hi, Could you solve this issue ? I am facing the same error. :/